Dudley's inequality: Sending $\delta$ to $0$
Let $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$ denote a mean-zero separable sub-Gaussian stochastic process with variance proxy $\sigma^2 = 1$, defined on some metric space $T$ with metric $d$.
Dudley's integral inequality, as stated in my textbook (Wainwright's high dimensional statistics) is given as:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t, s \in T} X_t - X_s\right] \leq 2 \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t, s \in T : d(t,s) < \delta} X_t - X_s\right] + 32 \int_{\delta/4}^\infty \sqrt{\log N(T,u,d)}du
$$
Here $N$ is the covering number of $T$ in the metric $d$ by balls of size $u$.
As a remark, he states that we may take $\delta \to 0$ and get the bound:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t, s \in T} X_t - X_s\right]  \leq 32 \int_{0}^\infty \sqrt{\log N(T,u,d)}du
$$
Question: As $\delta \to 0$, why is it the case that the first term:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t, s \in T : d(t,s) < \delta} X_t - X_s\right] 
$$
tends to $0$? I am not able to prove it as the only bounds I know are for finite collections of random variables. Even if I try to use some kind of compactness argument, the fact that the index set is infinite still gives me problems. Is there some assumption that is needed on the metric space $(T,d)$?

I just checked with Wainwright, seems like you miss a $2$ in front of the expectation. That's why I feel weird since you indeed get a $2$ when you derive the finite-resolution form.

A short answer is: you don't need additional assumption. To elaborate, in order to deduce $\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t, s\in T\colon d(t, s)<\delta}X_t - X_s]\to 0$ as $\delta\to 0$, I think separability for the process suffices.

Recall that we say a process is separable if there exists a countable $T_0 \subseteq T$ such that (outside a null set) for all $t \in T$, there exists $(t_n)$ in $T_0$ such that $d(t_n, t) \to 0$ satisfying $X_{t_n} \to X_t$.

This is the basic assumption we need for Dudley's entropy bound, and it basically gives $\sup_{t\in T_0} X_t = \sup_{t \in T} X_t$. Here, the metric space can be a pseudo-metric space, i.e., it needs not satisfy $d(x, y) > 0$ for $x \neq y$.
On the other hand, from what I understand, the logic is clearer if you consider the converse: Firstly, the latter bound is just the usual Dudley integral entropy bound:

(Dudley entropy bound) Let $\{X_t\}_{t\in T}$ be a centered and separable sub-Gaussian process on $(T, d)$ w.r.t. $d$. Then,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t\in T} X_t\right] 
\leq C\int_{0}^{\mathrm{diam}(T)}\sqrt{\log N(T, d, \epsilon)}\,\mathrm{d}\epsilon.
$$

In view of this, by triangle inequality, you get the bound for $X_t - X_s$ with a doubled constant $2C$. For what I know, $C=12$, but anyway it doesn't really matter.
You can then obtain the finite-resolution form of the above, i.e., separate the above bound by truncating the integral into $\int_{0}^{\delta} + \int_{\delta}^{\mathrm{dim}(T)}$. To be more specific, you will need to consider a minimal $\delta$-net $\mathcal{N}$ and decompose $X_t - X_s$ into
$$
X_t - X_s
= X_t - X_{\pi(t)} + X_{\pi(t)} - X_{\pi(s)} + X_{\pi(s)} - X_s,
$$
where $\pi(x)$ is the nearest element of $x$ in $\mathcal{N}$. You can further bound the right-hand side in the form of $2\sup_{t, s \in T\colon d(t, s)\leq \delta} (X_t - X_s) + \sup_{t', s' \in \mathcal{N}} (X_{t'} - X_{s'})$, which probably is a standard argument also used in your textbook. Then, you handle the second term by the usual Dudley's entropy bound with truncation. This gives what you have initially.
